# Show dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple question for you, at below it shows me value part of options. I need to show inner section like Veggies or Animals or All  when I select option.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 function dropdownTip(value){
    console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>



</head>
<body>
<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">Veggies</option>
    <option value="animals_search">Animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">All</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

     <script type="text/javascript">
     
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
       $('#result').text($(':selected',this).text());
    });
});
    </script>



    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
        <option value="veggies_search">Veggies</option>
        <option value="animals_search">Animals</option>
        <option value="all_search">All</option>
    </select>

    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I know that the question is tagged with jQuery, but isn't it a bit of an overkill to load an 84KB library for something that can be done in less than 84 characters in plain JavaScript? (Unless OP is using it already for other things)

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro probably, I'm assuming that one select isn't the whole webpage, that wouldn't be very exciting

Comment: Definitely not exciting at all :P